# Fullpage.js scrolling button

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I have a little problem I'm using `fullpage.js`. It works perfectly, but when I press the button `yes`, it scrolls to the section but it does not trigger any events. I activate my elements when my section has the active class but when i click on an element it does not trigger

#### HTML

```
<nav class="navig about"><a href="#about">about</a></nav>
<section class="description-joe section "data-anchor="about">
```

Comment: What is the button yes? Please provide the code or ideally an isolated reproduction of your issue in jsfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 0):

see this link: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#movetosection-slide

```
$(document).on('click', '#link-to-about-section', function () {
   //about section number-> ex:3
   $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(3);
   //or define  anchors: ['section1', 'section2', 'about', 'section4']
   $.fn.fullpage.moveTo('about', 1);
});
```